# Spring Boot: RestController xml deserialization and JAXB annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jaxb

How can I get Spring Boot's RestController to honour JAXB annotations when deserializing incoming XML to an object of a JAXB-annotated class? For example, given the following (I've tried to make this example minimal, with mixed results):

Build file (build.gradle):

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.10.RELEASE'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'

    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Main class:

```java
package org.example.jaxbbootissue;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Start {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Start.class, args);
    }
}
```

Web endpoint:

```java
package org.example.jaxbbootissue.web;

import org.example.jaxbbootissue.web.model.IncomingRequest;
import org.example.jaxbbootissue.web.model.OutgoingResponse;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Endpoint {
    @PostMapping("/greet", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public OutgoingResponse greet(@RequestBody IncomingRequest request) {
        String greeting = String.format("Hello, %s!", request.getName());
        OutgoingResponse response = new OutgoingResponse();
        response.setGreeting(greeting);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Request model (note the *required* attribute on the *name* field):

```java
package org.example.jaxbbootissue.web.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "request")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class IncomingRequest {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Response model:

```java
package org.example.jaxbbootissue.web.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class OutgoingResponse {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String greeting;

    public String getGreeting() {
        return greeting;
    }

    public void setGreeting(String greeting) {
        this.greeting = greeting;
    }
}
```

I'd expect the following tests to pass. But the second one (*shouldDenyInvalidRequest*) fails. The incoming message is deserialized to a *IncomingRequest* object with required field *name* being empty, and the server returns HTTP 200, instead of something like HTTP 400.

```java
package org.example.jaxbbootissue.web;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class EndpointTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void shouldAcceptValidRequest() throws Exception {
        String requestXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><request><name>John</name></request>";
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/greet")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .content(requestXml);
        mvc.perform(request).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDenyInvalidRequest() throws Exception {
        String requestXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><request></request>";
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/greet")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .content(requestXml);
        mvc.perform(request).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is4xxClientError());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDenyInvalidMimeType() throws Exception {
        String requestJson = "{ \"request\": { \"name\": \"John\" } }";
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/greet")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(requestJson);
        mvc.perform(request).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isUnsupportedMediaType());
    }
}
```

**Update**

Changed `@PostMapping(value = "/greet")` to `@PostMapping(value = "/greet", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)` in the web endpoint and added a new test case (*shouldDenyInvalidMimeType*) to better illustrate how I'd expect Spring to behave: fail before deserializing a faulty request and respond with the appropriate 4xx error.

Comment: You are testing against the actual http response codes here which will always be true as the request gets processed successfully. So if you want an error say 400 not found you will have to wrap your outgoing response in spring’s ResponseEntity with a proper http status code.

Comment: @Isankc You're right, assuming that the endpoint is actually called. But I'd expect Spring to throw an exception *before* calling the endpoint, while attempting to deserialize the request. I'll try to update the question to clear this up.

Comment: I get your point but still Spring will not throw an exception even when field name is set to empty. However, you can use @valid annotation from Spring Validator (you will have make changes to your Incoming request class also) to let spring control the validation and then you can make spring throw a field error.

Comment: @Isank What I'd like Spring to do is similar to what it does in case of, for example, wrong content-type. I've attached another test case to illustrate this. I'll look into this `@Valid` annotation, maybe that's what I need. But from what I get from your comment, it probably isn't. I'd like it to understand JAXB annotations, and the "...you will have to make changes to your IncomingRequest class..." doesn't bode well in this regard. :)

Comment: i am not sure, is spring boot configured to ingrate a Jaxb message converter? - we have a custom one, but we need to always configure it manually, not sure about the default one tough

Comment: @SimonSchrottner At least in 1.5.10.RELEASE, the `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` is configured by default.